# How to add additional data attributes to HTML element and access them in HTML in Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-material

I am trying to bind additional data to my html element other than value, as i need multiple things in my form. I'm adding a code snippet that shows what i want. I need to add a data attribute to mat-options so i can use it in mat-select-trigger. I'm getting asignees.value perfectly. But i also need "ID", how can i send that. If there's another way i can appreciate your help.

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [formControl]="asignees" multiple>
            <mat-select-trigger>
              {{asignees.value ? asignees.value[0] : ''}}
              {{asignees.data-id ? asignees.data-id[0] : ''}}
              <span *ngIf="asignees.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
                & {{asignees.value.length - 1}} more
              </span>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let member of projectMembers" [value]="member.data.name" [attr.data-id]="member.memberId">
              <div *ngIf="member.data.imageUrl === 'undefined' || !member.data.imageUrl"
                class="selectAsigneeNoImage">{{member.memberName}}</div>
              <img class="selectAsigneeImage" *ngIf="member.data.imageUrl !== 'undefined' && member.data.imageUrl"
                src="{{member.data.imageUrl}}">
              {{member.data.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: See: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3#add-the-input-hero-property

Comment: i tried it. But it doesn't work like i need it. Can you please elaborate using my scenario?